# Listar archivos en todas las carpetas de C:\ C#

Tags: c#

Necesito listar todos los archivos con extensión ".PST y .OST" en toda la unidad C:\

Me funciona el filtro para que solo me recoja los archivos con la extension ".PST y .OST" y los añada a un checklistBox.
Pero únicamente me funciona con los archivos que estan en la raiz de la unidad C y no en todos los directorios de la unidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        //DirectoryInfo dirPrograms = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");

        var dirs = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pst") || s.EndsWith(".ost"));

        try
        {

            foreach (var di in dirs)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(di);
            }

        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
           
        }
```

Comment: Con .net 5.0 hay una opción `IgnoreInaccessible` que evitaría el problema que tienes. (yo nunca lo he probado la verdad). Si trabajas con versiones anteriores, es sencillo crearte tu propio método recursivo para ir buscando en todo el disco (aunque será muy lento y podría dar algun problema de memoria dependiendo de la jerarquía de tus carpetas). Si quieres te pongo como sería ese metodo

Comment: Si, porfavor.
Me ayudaria mucho saber como se utiliza para futuros proyectos.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar tu propio método recursivo para buscar en tus carpetas usando [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-5.0). Te pongo un ejemplo que utilicé yo hace un tiempo:

```
private void SearchDirectory(string path, List<string> file_list)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir_info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    try
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir_info in dir_info.GetDirectories())
        {
            SearchDirectory(subdir_info.FullName, file_list);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    try
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file_info in dir_info.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file_info.Extension==".pst" || file_info.Extension==".ost")
            file_list.Add(file_info.FullName);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Los `try/catch` vacios aunque no son muy "esteticos" evitan las excepciones que se producen al intentar acceder a carpetas para las que no se tienen permiso de acceso.

La forma de usar este método es sencilla:

```
List<string> file_list = new List<string>();
SearchDirectory(@"c:\", file_list);
```

Como te decía en mi comentario, probablemente no es un método muy eficiente, pero espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando es listar los archivos **recursivamente**, es decir, listar todos los archivos dentro de una carpeta y los archivos dentro de las carpetas que tiene adentro, y así sucesivamente. En tu caso, la línea que hace el indexado debería ser así:

```cs
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories, EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pst") || s.EndsWith(".ost"));
```

Si el tiempo de cómputo de esta tarea no es problema para tu programa, estaría bien, pero si es importante que funcione óptimamente, tendrás que buscar otra forma de implementarlo, porque indexar la raíz del disco C: recursivamente suele tomar mucho tiempo, simplemente porque tiene que trabajar en probablemente cientos de miles de archivos y carpetas.

Comment: He intentado crear el proyecto de nuevo en .NET 5 y tampoco me funciona al utilizar "EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories)"
Me aparece que no existe esa opcion.

He intentado añadir ademas el siguiente codigo:

 public bool RecurseSubdirectories
        {
            set { RecurseSubdirectories = true; }
        }
        public bool IgnoreInaccessible
        {
            set { IgnoreInaccessible = true; }
        }

Y tampoco me funciona correctamente. No lista ningun archivo.